# Stuck trying to figure out a hidden message: Sharknado

Tags: cipher, steganography

As part of an ongoing "treasure hunt" in an online game that I take part in, there have been several forum posts made in an attempt to hint the participants to finding certain locations. However, these clues are hidden within regular forum posts; they have contained anything from a small font white text line of hexcode to convert, to "first letter of each sentence" deals. The latest ones, though, has been a succession of posts that I have not been able to wrap my head around.

The biggest clue appears to be in the punctuation of these posts as there are numerous extra spaces between sentences (and the amount varies) as well as extra periods - sometimes one period closes a sentence, sometimes there will be 5.

I've been trying to look around on google for ways to crack this and get a location clue, but so far, I've not had any luck. I can not start to decypher these clues if I don't even know what kind of clues they are!

What sort of steganography or cryptography methods could be utilizing extra spaces and periods, but only at the end of sentences? I've tried SNOW, I've attempted to look for zero-width-characters, I've tried to figure out if it was morse code, or even binary, but so far to no avail.

[Example](https://pastebin.com/eBtMM72u):

```
#5 - Sharknado Time!!!!!  They must defeat 5 waves of land sharks!
 
wave 1 - 6 Sharks in Wolf Skin Clothing - Champion size! - not a bad challenge...  they got through that fairly easy.
 
wave 2 - 3 Wild Ham Sharks - not as easy as I thought they would be... good good!
 
wave 3 - 8 fierce Sharklins - hmm they fight like House Elves but were no match against cold hard steel.  "<Wargasm> Says the "healthy" one...."
 
wave 4 - 4 Barber Sharks from Hell! - Now we have a fight going on!  Carper and Wargasm both had to retreat and work on a new defense strategy while they worked to reintroduce blood to their emptied veins.  When the barber keeps wanting to take a little off the top, eventually it becomes too much off the top.  Unfortunately for Carper and Wargasm these barbers were cutting from the ankles up.  The battle continued as the challengers worked to heal up multiple times from all the cuts during the wave, but eventually after several very close calls, the barbers were put out of business.
 
wave 5 - A Loanshark!  You have always heard of these and if fortunate you never found any.  They tend to pool together at the bottom of the muddy lakes and lay at the bottom waiting for their hapless victims to fall into deep waters.  The Loanshark hammered Carper and Wargasm with stacks of fees and bloody high interests rates, but in the end Carper and Wargasm found a loophole in the Loansharks armor and bled it dry.
 
 
 
For their winnings, Wargasm received a supreme pizza of divine fulfillment and a couple of pastries.
 
Carper received a rare saddle, a fine fishing rod of perch fishing, a bee smoker which I was not aware that they did.....  a supreme mountain lion rug of... a dead cat.... a rare smelting pot for melting down silvers and coppers, and finally 2 supreme pizzas of grand cheesy health, along with 4 pastries... blueberry I think...  and a bird statue.
```

Comment: You're selling it wrong, mate. Paste the link in the puzzle and rename the puzzle to "Sharknado hidden message" or stuff.

Comment: Is this an ongoing competition? If so, unfortunately our policy requires the question be closed so as not to advantage/disadvantage certain competitors. Regardless, please [attach a direct link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) to the competition or as close to that as you can, since without a link or more detailed reference this is plagarism.

Comment: Im not looking for someone to solve the clue - I'm just trying to figure out what sort of encryption is being used so that I can attempt to solve it myself. There's not really a direct link as it's not a competition, but secret messages hidden throughout various random forum posts among regular posts - it'd require a bunch of different links to what are suspected hints. Sharknado is only part of a post out of dozens and is more as an example of the punctuation. The question still remains as far as what kind of ways exist to hide a secret message using extra spaces and periods?